# Printing a selected portion from multiple tags of same name of XML files using python

Tags: python, xml-parsing

1. Hello,
              I have my XML file something like this,  Can someone help me in
              fetching a particular tag from the XML file:

   ```
              <A1>
               <A><B>TEST1</B></A>
               <A><B>TEST2</B></A>
               <A><B>TEST3</B></A>
              </A1>

               <A1>
               <A><B>TEST4</B></A>
               <A><B>TEST5</B></A>
               <A><B>TEST6</B></A>
              </A1>
   ```

Till now I am handling it in python like this:

```
              for A in A1.findall('A'):
                   B = A.find('B').text
                   print B

      print B is giving me output like this:

          Test1
          Test2
          Test3
          Test4
          Test5
          Test6


   I want output from only first tag like this:

          Test1
          Test4


   What changes should I do to make it work?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, let's try again. So, following the revision, we want to search through the doc, and every time the parent tag (A1) occurs, we want to grab the contents of the first tag in each set.

Let's try a recursive function:

```
xmlData = open('xml.txt').readlines()
xml = ''.join(xmlData)

def grab(xml):
        """ Recursively walks through the whole XML data until <A1> is not found"""

        # base case, if the parent tag (<A1>) isn't there, then return
    if xml.find('<A1>') == -1:
        return 
    else:
                # find the location of the parent tag
        open_parent = xml.find('<A1>')
        close_parent = open_parent + 4

        # find the first child tag
        open_child = xml.find('<a><b>', close_parent)
        close_child = xml.find('</b></a>', open_child)

                # grab the data within that tag
        child_data = xml[open_child + 6 : close_child]
        print(child_data)

                # recursively call the grab() function
        return grab(xml[close_child:])
```

Out of interest, do you already have a solution for this that you wouldn't mind sharing as well?

Comment: Hello, Nick I am sorry for incomplete information, Can you re-read the question and answer it. I have edited the original question

Comment: Hi, tough one! You have probably already got your answer to this, but I have modified the answer above anyway. Thanks for the good question!